# Get screen size in px on Android N with changed display zoom

Tags: android, size, screen, pixel, android-7.0-nougat

I have a problem with the calculation of the display size on Android N with a changed display zoom.

With Android N you can change the display zoom (check [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/10/android-n-feature-spotlight-easily-change-your-devices-display-dpi-with-screen-zoom/))
but the display size (...getSize()) doesn't change if the user sets a zoom from android settings...

Any idea to solve it? Have I to use the size in px multiplied by scaledDensity to have a real display size?

My app dinamically creates windows and components calculating screen dimensions in px, the components are designed on a server.
Briefly I do a math proportion by the width set on the server and the width of the smartphone screen :

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
   display.getRealSize(sizePoint);
}else{
   display.getSize(sizePoint);
}
int smartphoneDisplayWidth =  sizePoint.x;
int smartphoneDisplayHeight = sizePoint.y;

int serverDisplayWidth = 720px; //this come from the server
int serverComponentWidth = 720px; //this come from the server
int smartphoneComponentWidth = (smartphoneDisplayWidth/serverDisplayWidth)*serverComponentWidth;
//ex: smartphoneComponentWidth = (1080/720)*720 = 1080; the component widht on the smartphone will be 1080px.
```

If i set a smaller zoom I have this problem:
**default**:
[image]
**small**:
the windows components are to small:
[image]

The width in px doesn't change, it changes only the density:

small

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.2250001, width=1080, height=1813, scaledDensity=2.2250001, xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069}
```

default

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.625,     width=1080, height=1794, scaledDensity=2.625,     xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069}
```

large

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.875,     width=1080, height=1782, scaledDensity=2.875,     xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069}
```

larger

```
DisplayMetrics{density=3.125,     width=1080, height=1770, scaledDensity=3.125,      xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069}
```

largest

```
DisplayMetrics{density=3.375,     width=1080, height=1758, scaledDensity=3.375,      xdpi=422.03, ydpi=424.069}
```

Comment: may be a solution this?
`int smartphoneComponentWidth = ((smartphoneDisplayWidth*scaledDensity) / serverDisplayWidth) * serverComponentWidth;`

Comment: The ability to zoom on Android N is beyond the scope of applications. In addition if you incorporate in your application functions only existing an Android N you are limiting a lot the quantity of possible clients.

Answer (score 1):

You should create views using dp value instead of px. When density changes (like in nugat settings) you see the result in second screen.

Probably you create layout like this:

```
int screenWidth = <value>;
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(screenWidth, 200);
view.setlayoutparams(lp);
```

You should use density:

```
float sampleDensity = 2f; // get from DisplayMetrics
int screenWidth = <value>;
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth * sampleDensity), 200);
view.setlayoutparams(lp);
```

Other reason is maybe you not update layouts after configuration change. Better solution is use `MATCH_PARENT` and `WRAP_CONTENT` in LayoutParams. Its more convenient and fast solution.

Comment: Yes, multiplying the with by the scaled density? take a look on my comments.
I can't use MATCH and WRAP beacuse the app is totally dynamic, configured on a web server, and it have to works on iOS and Android :-)

Comment: Multiplying the width and sampleDensity doesn't work.
I think you have to multiply width and the difference of density by the default and other densities (small, large or other)...
Any other suggestions?